# PHP date() warning when passing data from SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a set of XML data like this.

```
<data>
    <person>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <date>343658755</date>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <date>655389955</date>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Cathy</name>
        <date>741876355</date>
    </person>
</data>
```

Using PHP I am parsing it with `SimpleXMLElement` and trying to display the timestamp in a date format.

```php
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $data->person[0]->date);
```

This displays the following warning.

```
Warning:  date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in ....
```

Echoing `$data->person[0]->date` displays the timestamp without any problems. `var_dump()` shows the following output.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "343658755"
}
```

How do I "refer" to this string directly? If this string is inside an object why is there no Error/Warning when I echo it?

The only way I could make it work with the `date()` function is to convert it to the integer type like this.

```php
echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', (int) $data->person[0]->date );
```

Does it work with all versions of PHP? Is there anything bad about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. `date()` function expects  the parameter to be a long, but you're passing a SimpleXML object instead.

As is evident from the `var_dump()` output `$data->person[0]->date` is an object. To get just the timestamp part, you'd have to cast it to a string.

This is applicable everywhere. When working SimpleXML, you'd have to explicitly cast the object into a string in order to access the contents inside. For this particular case, the following should work:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (string) $data->person[0]->date);
```

Comment: Is `(string)` better than `(int)`? PHP's `date()` function accepts an integer for timestamp.

Comment: @A.Jesin: Not really. `(int)` may not work for cases when there are string characters too, whereas `(string)` would. Although in this case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @A.Jesin `(string)` result to calling `__toString` method of `SimpleXMLElement`. `(int)` has no such equivalent. So if you want to apply `(int)` you have to apply `(string)` first anyway

Comment: `$data->person[0]->date->__toString()`, `sprintf('%s', $data->person[0]->date);` or `echo` with output buffering... There are many ways to skin this cat.